# Google Chrome font optimization

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

i heavily use Google Fonts and custom fonts, as Google Chrome has a bad habit of rendering them poorly, which is a shame because everything else works so well with Google Chrome, is there any way i can (preferably using css) render the fonts to an 'Apple Safari' standard?

Thanks,

Comment: By "render poorly" - what exactly do you mean? Pixelated? Not kerned properly? Do you have any screen shots to compare?

Comment: Also, what OS/hardware are you comparing to please?  An old CRT running Windows XP will look different than on iPad3 or even a MacBook, due to what font-types OS can handle & the actual screen.

Comment: Safari does have its own rendering engine, which is AFAIK not part of the open source Webkit package. So it's not a matter of changing some settings in Chrome to have it display the same; Chrome simply doesn't have it.

Comment: I suspect this is about the different font rendering approaches used in Safari (same as OSX) and Windows (ClearType).

Comment: There was a hack. I found it once and can't find it again :( I hope someone posts a good answer to this.

Comment: I can send you this link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbokdhnlldmknaijpgikegjffnlpaamk?hl=en-US this is extension for chrome. It makes fonts in chrome like a safari. Usually it makes **CSS text-shadow** and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ever confounding question. (see: https://superuser.com/questions/354006/google-chrome-never-renders-fonts-properly-no-smoothing-etc. See also: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oXILHkVG75M)

It's a Windows 7/Vista ClearType issue. AFAIK Safari, FF and IE render text differently or use their own text rendering routines. Basically, it used to be that you could add a small shadow to set an internal Chrome rendering flag, and the text would look decently better, but it still looks pretty bad. That no longer works. As far as I can tell it's a bug in Chrome that hasn't been fixed.

I'm still looking for a work-around myself, but I think we're pretty much out of luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look into -webkit-font-smoothing ? I regularly use Google Fonts and @font-face kits and have had success with some of the '*chunkier*' fonts using the 'subpixel-antialiased' and 'antialiased':

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Perhaps try each and see if either makes a difference to what you're seeing?

There's a post on MaxVoltar that gives a reasonable explanation:

http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing